# Pipe each stdout line to a comand on windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, pipe, xargs, tshark

Can I/how do I pipe **each line** of output from a command to another command *(on Windows)*.

For example I have `tshark` which outputs:

```
1   0.000000 1.1.1.1 -> 1.1.1.2 TLSv1.2 85 Application Data
2   0.000726 1.1.1.2 -> 1.1.1.1 TLSv1.2 89 Application Data
3   0.064803 1.1.1.3 -> 1.1.1.2 TLSv1 155 Application Data
4   0.155403 1.1.1.1 -> 1.1.1.2 TCP 60 443â┼'62745 [ACK] Seq=32 Ack=36 Win=374 Len=0
5   0.268586 1.1.1.2 -> 1.1.1.3 TCP 54 56149â┼'443 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=102 Win=63331 Len=0
6   0.730557 1.1.1.2 -> 1.1.1.4 UDP 45 Source port: 46586  Destination port: 52531
7   1.069927  1.1.1.5 -> 1.1.1.2 TCP 60 40020â┼'50293 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=136 Len=3
8   1.179893 fe00::dd00:9f00:dd00:1e00 -> ff00::c      SSDP 208 M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1
9   1.269580 1.1.1.2 -> 1.1.1.5  TCP 54 50293â┼'40020 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=4 Win=16130 Len=0
```

And I want to execute `my-prog.bat` on each line, e.g:

```
my-prog.exe   1   0.000000 1.1.1.1 -> 1.1.1.2 TLSv1.2 85 Application Data
my-prog.exe   2   0.000726 1.1.1.2 -> 1.1.1.1 TLSv1.2 89 Application Data
my-prog.exe   3   0.064803 1.1.1.3 -> 1.1.1.2 TLSv1 155 Application Data
my-prog.exe   4   0.155403 1.1.1.1 -> 1.1.1.2 TCP 60 443â┼'62745 [ACK] Seq=32 Ack=36 Win=374 Len=0
my-prog.exe   5   0.268586 1.1.1.2 -> 1.1.1.3 TCP 54 56149â┼'443 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=102 Win=63331 Len=0
my-prog.exe   6   0.730557 1.1.1.2 -> 1.1.1.4 UDP 45 Source port: 46586  Destination port: 52531
my-prog.exe   7   1.069927  1.1.1.5 -> 1.1.1.2 TCP 60 40020â┼'50293 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=136 Len=3
my-prog.exe   8   1.179893 fe00::dd00:9f00:dd00:1e00 -> ff00::c      SSDP 208 M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1
my-prog.exe   9   1.269580 1.1.1.2 -> 1.1.1.5  TCP 54 50293â┼'40020 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=4 Win=16130 Len=0
```

My `my-prog.bat` is simply `echo %TIME% %* >> test.txt`

I tried a few things like (using GnuWin xargs):

```
tshark | xargs my-prog.bat
tshark | xargs -n1 my-prog.bat
```

But the best I got was outputing litterally `%*` to the file. (`my-prog.bat test` works as expected and appends `test` to the file)

(Note that `tshark` will continue to run until CTRL+C is pressed)

Answer (score 2):

First verify that tshark sends its output to stdout. If you run `tshark >nul` and get no output, then it is indeed using stdout, and all is good.

If you still see output, then try stderr using `tshark 2>nul`. If this eliminates the output, then you must redirect stderr to stdout using `tshark 2>&1`.

If neither of the above eliminate the output on the screen, then you are out of luck.

Now you want to pipe the output to a batch script that will add a timestamp prefix to each line of output. There are a number of complications:

- The output contains the `>` character, which is interpreted as a redirection operation when you call your batch script. The offending character would need to be quoted or escaped. Escaping is a pain, and quoting will add unwanted quotes to your ultimate output.
- You need to terminate the tshark process by pressing `<Ctrl-C>`, but that terminates both sides of the pipe, and your right hand side will prompt if you want to terminate the batch script, but there is no more input - and it hangs

In my original answer I thought you could eliminate the pipe and process the lines via FOR /F. But FOR /F does not begin iterating until the command finishes, so that can't work.

The best solution I have come up with is to use JScript (or VBS could work) on the right side of a pipe to add the timestamp prefix.

Assuming your left side never prompts for input without issuing a new line, then you could use:

**addTS.js**

```
while( !WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream ) {
  var time = new Date;
  WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(   zpad(time.getHours(),2) + ":"
                            + zpad(time.getMinutes(),2) + ":"
                            + zpad(time.getSeconds(),2) + '.'
                            + zpad(time.getMilliseconds(),3) + "  "
                            + WScript.StdIn.ReadLine()
                          );
}

function zpad(num, size) {
  var s = "000" + num;
  return s.substr(s.length-size);
}
```

***usage:***

```
tshark|cscript //nologo addTS.js
```

If your left side ever asks for input without issuing a new line, then you won't see the prompt until you provide the input. That doesn't work well. So here is a modified version of addTS.js that reads and writes each character individually:

```
var time, chr, newLine=true;
while( !WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream ) {
  chr=WScript.StdIn.Read(1);
  if (newLine) {
    time = new Date();
    WScript.StdOut.Write(   zpad(time.getHours(),2) + ":"
                          + zpad(time.getMinutes(),2) + ":"
                          + zpad(time.getSeconds(),2) + '.'
                          + zpad(time.getMilliseconds(),3) + "  "
                        );
    newLine=false;
  }
  WScript.StdOut.Write(chr);
  newLine=(chr=='\n');
}

function zpad(num, size) {
  var s = "000" + num;
  return s.substr(s.length-size);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work. `tshark > nul` works as expected. But your middle example only seems to write after `ctrl+c` is pressed (rather than after each line). Using the first/last example doesn't work at all.

Comment: @Petah - I forgot that FOR /F does not begin iterating the lines of output until the command has completed, so my original solution can't work. I've updated my answer with a JScript solution that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('tshark') do (my-prog.bat %%a)
```

Which does exactly what you want.

**Note**: This is for batch-files. If you want to do this straight in Command Prompt, then you would have to replace `%%a` with `%a`

### Alternative Solution

I've just noticed, the end result here is having a log file full of the data from `tshark`. If that's the case you could just:

```
tshark > test.txt
```

Which is the same result as calling `my-prog.bat` It will also do it line by line, so you can leave it running indefinitely. I've tested it on my computer (by running `dir /s > test.txt` in `C:` and while it was running `type test.txt` and there were already lines in it though the command hadn't finished yet).

Comment: Hmm that does seem to work for `dir`, but that was an example command, I am using `tshark` (sorry for the that). I will reword my question.

Comment: @Petah Try my new solution

Comment: Unfortunately that does not seem to execute the `my-prog.bat` command. Nothing is output to `test.txt`

Comment: I've put up an alternative solution, the problem with the first one might have to do with the `Ctrl-C` thing

Comment: I can see where you are going with that, but I want to call `my-prog.bat` in real  time, line by line, not after `tshark` ends (i.e. leave `tshark` running indefinitely)

Comment: I think doing `tshark > test.txt` would do it line by line, let me check. @Petah look at my new update. I have tested it and it works

Comment: Again I am sorry if I was overly general with my question, but I need to pipe to a command not just write a file. For example if I modified `my-prog.bat` to be `echo %TIME% %* >> cap.txt`

Comment: I am actually starting to think this might be an issue with tshark rather than standard tools...